# How to allow my java script to resolve the relative URL as ~/ does in razor view

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have an asp.net mvc web application , which is deployed under /sites as follow:-

```
 http://servername/sites/
```

but if i reference the URL as follow:-

```
url:'/ControllerName/ActionMethodName'
```

the result will be `http://servername/ControllerName/ActionMethodName` and NOT `http://servername/ControllerName/sites/ActionMethodName`
i usually solve this issue inside my razor view by writting the following:-

`url: "@Url.Content("~/ControllerName/ActionMethodName")"` . but seems that javascript does snot have the same ability. so can anyone advice?
Thanks

Comment: remove the initial slash `url:'ControllerName/ActionMethodName'`

Comment: this will result in adding the current URL path to the url in javascript which i want to avoid ...as i want to call an action method that is different than the one i am current browsing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this, not so elegant.
I prefer to put a Hidden field in _Layout.cshtml (or any other master page)

```
@Html.Hidden("HiddenCurrentUrl",  Url.Content("~"))
```

In a common js file:

```
var baseUrl = "";
$(document).ready(function () {
    baseUrl = $("#HiddenCurrentUrl").val();
});
```

Then just refer Urls like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: baseUrl + 'solicitacoes/obtertipo/' + value
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure yet about this practice, but it worked for me (fixing tons of legacy code)

In your javascript file, use variables for all paths.

```
 var ActionSubmit;
```

In your View include this:

```
 <script>
 ActionSubmit = '@(@Url.Content("~/ControllerName/ActionMethodName")';
 </script>
```